# Distinct one column and display other columns below

Tags: sql, distinct

I am sure I am looking at this in the wrong way.

I would like to hold a restaurant menu in a database and display it.  For example, I have created a table similar to the one below:

**Columns:**

```
Food_Item | Food_Description | Food_Price | Food_CAT.
```

**Data:**

Salad | Refreshing Salad | 5.25 | Starters
Prawn Cocktail | Lovely Prawns | 4.75 | Starters
Tomato Soup | Cream of tomatoe | 4.50 | Soups
Steak | Lovely Rump Steak | 10.95 | Mains
Fish & Chips | Classc dish | 8.75 | Mains

What I am trying to achieve is a menu layout, where the food_CAT acts as the header and then the different dishes are presented below, for example:

**Starters**
Salad - 5.25
Prawn Cocktail - 4.75

**Soups**
Tomato Soup - 4.50

**Mains**
Steak - 10.95
Fish & Chips

etc..

Is there an easy way to do this, so that I don't have the food_cat header above each dish, only over the first one? I thought I could use DISTINCT, however from reading other posts, I understand it's near impossible to DISTINCT one column.

Hope somebody can help.

Regards,
Oliver

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is in the display, not in the query.

Include `Food_CAT` in the `SELECT` statement for the query. It will be included in each record retrieved.

Use `ORDER BY` to sort the items first by `Food_CAT` and then by whatever column you want, probably `Food_Item` or `Food_Description`.

Then, in whatever method you choose to display the results, you iterate through the query, adding a row displaying only `Food_CAT` each time the value of that field changes. After that header record is displayed, you display the records which match that `Food_CAT`, and so on.

Comment: Hi DOK.  Could you explain how to only display the value of a field when that field changes?  Thanks

Comment: That depends on when and how you are displaying the results. One approach would be to add a column ModifiedDate to the table, and then SELECT WHERE ModifiedDate is greater than some base date. Another approach would involve database triggers (when the record changes), but that seems awfully complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm under the impression that you're asking how to do this in a SELECT statement, not with cursors. If that's not the case, there's a better answer using cursors that can eliminate some of the flotsam in my answer. There are also reporting-tool-specific answers that are far better than both of these (but you don't mention use of a reporting tool).

The key is that you have two data sets you want to intermingle:

- The list of headers
- The item and the price

First step to combine them is to make the data sets match, so you'll want to combine the item and price into a single string. The next is to include the data you want to sort by, which is food_cat, and something that will sort headers to the top of a food_cat, and the item/price string below that. What you end up with looks something like:

```
select distinct food_cat as display, 
 food_cat, 
 1 as sort_order
from temp_food

union

select food_item + ' - ' + cast (food_price as varchar), 
 food_cat, 
 2
from temp_food

order by food_cat, sort_order
```

Of course, you have extra columns in this data set you don't want displayed, but that's something you'll have to deal with on another level.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

SQL isn't very good at mixing and matching different kinds of rows in a single resultset i.e. it would take an overly-complex query to return data in a single resultset like this:

```
Starters | n/a
Salad | 5.25
Prawn Cocktail | 4.75
Soups | n/a
Tomato Soup | 4.50
Mains | n/a
Steak | 10.95
Fish & Chips | 8.75
```

You'd be better off using a JOIN to link the data horizontally, and then do a little processing in your client app to display the data in a menu structure.

```
SELECT Food_CAT, Food_Item, Food_Price FROM xx ORDER BY Food_CAT
```

Then in the client app, loop through the resultset something like this:

```
$foodtype = '' // a variable to store which category of food you're currently on
FOR EACH row in myresults:
  IF myresults.Food_CAT <> $foodtype // another item in the existing category
    PRINT myresults.Food_Item + myresults.Food_Price
  ELSE // new category
    $foodtype = myresults.Food_CAT
    PRINT blankline
    PRINT myresults.Food_CAT
    PRINT myresults.Food_Item + myresults.Food_Price
```

Comment: thanks vincebowdren, that looks good, I will give it a try later.  I must admit, I was really struggling with this, and resorted to cheating.  I decided to use jQuery to filter the food_cat results and remove all headers after the first. OK, it won't degrade gracefully but it was a working answer.  I will definitely give your  answer a go.  thanks.